# Timeout / # Pending Requests in ZMQ REQ/REP Pattern

Tags: message-queue, soa, zeromq

I'm considering to start using ZMQ REQ/REP rather than straight-up HTTP for my SOA environment. But I'm fairly new at using MQs for this purpose, so I have a couple of questions.

Q1. When using HTTP, I can set a simple timeout and raise an alert if server A can't talk to server B. Based on my currently understanding of ZMQ, ZMQ will simply have server A wait for server B to reconnect and I won't know there is a problem. How do I get around this?

Q2. How do I gain an overall picture of how many requests are currently pending/enqueued, and possibly fetch the list for investigative purposes?

Max

Answer (score 1):

> Q1. When using HTTP, I can set a simple timeout and raise an alert if
>   server A can't talk to server B. Based on my currently understanding
>   of ZMQ, ZMQ will simply have server A wait for server B to reconnect
>   and I won't know there is a problem. How do I get around this?

Don't use REQ/REP; use DEALER and ROUTER on client and server, respectively; they are more versatile, asynchronous, and won't block like rep/req.

For timeouts, you can set one explicitly, or, use a poller, a better choice as it provides more flexibility, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7540299/791406).

> How do I gain an overall picture of how many requests are currently
>   pending/enqueued, and possibly fetch the list for investigative
>   purposes?

I don't believe this is possible, not in 3.x at least. In general, such details are abstracted by zmq.

Comment: Thanks. For Q2, if that is not possible, then how do I know if there's a bottleneck with a lot of requests filling up, and how do I know if the entire queue is cleared/flushed?

Comment: Zeromq sockets have receive and send buffers, depending on the type (some have both). If the socket buffer exceeds the high water mark (HWM), it will either drop, or block, additional messages (read this http://api.zeromq.org/3-2:zmq-socket), again depending on socket type. You must test and measure to find bottlenecks, and adjust the HWM accordingly. Also, there is no "flush"; to clear messages sitting in buffer, the socket must be closed. Read the faq, many of these questions are addressed, hope it helps! http://zeromq.org/area:faq