# zero-mq: socket.recv() call is blocking

Tags: python, zeromq

I am trying to use zero-mq.My requirement is very simple.I want to be able to communicate between two peers in a network.I came across this program in the examples in the book.

`$ pub_server.py`

```
import zmq
import random
import sys
import time

port = "5556"
if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    port =  sys.argv[1]
    int(port)

context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
socket.bind("tcp://*:%s" % port)

while True:
    topic = random.randrange(9999,10005)
    messagedata = random.randrange(1,215) - 80
    print "%d %d" % (topic, messagedata)
    socket.send("%d %d" % (topic, messagedata))
    time.sleep(1)
```

`$sub_client.py`

```
import sys
import zmq

port = "5556"
if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    port =  sys.argv[1]
    int(port)

# Socket to talk to server
context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)

print "Collecting updates from weather server..."
socket.connect ("tcp://localhost:%s" % port)

# Subscribe to zipcode, default is NYC, 10001
topicfilter = "10001"
socket.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, topicfilter)

# Process 5 updates
total_value = 0
for update_nbr in range (5):
    string = socket.recv()
    topic, messagedata = string.split()
    total_value += int(messagedata)
    print ('{} {}'.format(topic, messagedata))

print('Avg data value for topic {} was {}'.format(topicfilter, (total_value/update_nbr)))
```

The problem I have with this model is that

`string = socket.recv()`

blocks till I recieve a message.I don't want this to happen.I want the messages to be queued up on the recieve side so that I can get it out of the queue (or something similar to this)

Is there some model in zero-mq that allows this?

Comment: Use `zmq.Poller` as described in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7540299/202775

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[zmq.Socket.recv](http://zeromq.github.io/pyzmq/api/zmq.html#zmq.Socket.recv) will not block if you pass the `zmq.NOBLOCK` flag parameter.

The docs say:

```
If NOBLOCK is set, this method will raise a ZMQError with EAGAIN if a message is not ready.
```

zmq will queue messages that it receives and one message will be returned for each recv() call until this queue is exhausted after which ZMQError is raised.

[zmq.Again](https://pyzmq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/zmq.html#zmq.Again) used in the examples below is a `wrapper for zmq.EAGAIN`.

For example:

```
while True:
    try:
        #check for a message, this will not block
        message = socket.recv(flags=zmq.NOBLOCK)

        #a message has been received
        print "Message received:", message

    except zmq.Again as e:
        print "No message received yet"

    # perform other important stuff
    time.sleep(10)
```

The `sub_client.py` example could perhaps be written to use non-blocking behaviour like this:

```
import sys, time
import zmq

port = "5556"
if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    port =  sys.argv[1]
    int(port)

# Socket to talk to server
context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)

print "Collecting updates from weather server..."
socket.connect ("tcp://localhost:%s" % port)

# Subscribe to zipcode, default is NYC, 10001
topicfilter = "10001"
socket.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, topicfilter)

# Process 5 updates
total_value = 0
received_value_count = 0
do_receive_loop = True
while do_receive_loop:
    try:
        #process all messages waiting on subscribe socket
        while True:
            #check for a message, this will not block
            string = socket.recv(flags=zmq.NOBLOCK)

            #message received, process it
            topic, messagedata = string.split()
            total_value += int(messagedata)
            print ('{} {}'.format(topic, messagedata))

            #check if we have all the messages we want
            received_value_count += 1
            if received_value_count > 4:
                do_receive_loop = False
                break

    except zmq.Again as e:
        #No messages waiting to be processed
        pass

    #Here we can do other stuff while waiting for messages
    #contemplate answer to 'The Last Question'
    time.sleep(15)
    print "INSUFFICIENT DATA FOR MEANINGFUL ANSWER"

print('Avg data value for topic {} was {}'.format(topicfilter, (total_value/5)))
```