# ZeroMQ Pub/Sub action last element in queue an other elements

Tags: python, sockets, zeromq, publish-subscribe

I started using `zeromq` with python with the [Publisher/Subscriber](http://learning-0mq-with-pyzmq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyzmq/patterns/pubsub.html) reference. However, I don't find any documentation about how to treat messages in the queue. I want to treat the last received message different as the rest of the elements of the queue.

### Example

#### publisher.py

```
import zmq
import random
import time

port = "5556"
topic = "1"

context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
socket.bind("tcp://*:%s" % port)

while True:
    messagedata = random.randrange(1,215)
    print "%s %d" % (topic, messagedata)
    socket.send("%s %d" % (topic, messagedata))
    time.sleep(.2)
```

#### subscriber.py

```
import zmq

port = "5556"
topic = "1"

context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)

print "Connecting..."
socket.connect ("tcp://localhost:%s" % port)
socket.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE,topic)

while True:
    if isLastMessage(): # probably based on socket.recv()
         analysis_function() # time consuming function
    else:
         simple_function()  # something simple like print and save in memory
```

I just want to know how to create the `isLastMessage()` function described in the `subscriber.py` file. If there's something directly in `zeromq` or a workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I will keep the question for reference. I just found the answer, in the documentation there is a `NOBLOCK` flag that you can add to the receiver. With this the `recv` command doesn't block. A simple workaround, extracted from a part of an [answe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26014197/2237916)r, is the following:

```
while True:
    try:
        #check for a message, this will not block
        message = socket.recv(flags=zmq.NOBLOCK)

        #a message has been received
        print "Message received:", message

    except zmq.Again as e:
        print "No message received yet"
```

As for the real implementation, one is not sure that it is the last call you use the flag `NOBLOCK` and once you have entered the `exception` block. Wich translates to something like the following:

```
msg = subscribe(in_socket)
is_last = False
while True:
    if is_last:
        msg = subscribe(in_socket)
        is_last = False
    else:
        try:
            old_msg = msg
            msg = subscribe(in_socket,flags=zmq.NOBLOCK)
            # if new message was received, then process the old message
            process_not_last(old_msg)
        except zmq.Again as e:
            process_last(msg)
            is_last = True  # it is probably the last message
```

Answer (score 2):

### Welcome to the world of non-blocking messaging / signalling

this is a cardinal feature for any serious distributed-system design.

If you assume a "last" message via a not having another one in the pipe, then a `Poller()` instance may help your main event-loops, where you may control the amount of time to "wait"-a-bit before considering the pipe "empty", not to devastate your IO-resources with zero-wait spinning-loops.

### Explicit signalling is always better  <sup>( if you can design the remote end behaviour )</sup>

There is Zero-knowledge on the receiver-side, what is the context of the "last"-message received ( and explicit signalling is advised to be rather broadcast from the message sender-side ), however there is a reversed feature to this -- that instructs ZeroMQ archetypes to "internally"-throw away all such messages, that are not the "last"-message, thus reducing the receiver-side processing to right the "last"-message available.

```
aQuoteStreamMESSAGE.setsockopt( zmq.CONFLATE, 1 )
```

If you may like to read more on ZeroMQ patterns and anti-patterns, do not miss Pieter HINTJENS' fabulous book "Code Connected, Volume 1" ( also in pdf ) and may like a broader view on [distributed-computing](/questions/tagged/distributed-computing) using [principally a **non-blocking ZeroMQ approach**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45534028)

Comment: I'm really starting with all this interprocess communication stuff. I've been trying to play around even with shared memory and semaphores lately. Anyway, I'll check out the `CONFLATE` flag, as well as some flags that I still don't know.

Comment: Definitely worth to read the PDF-book, before diving into any code. Zero-sharing, Zero-blocking, (almost)-Zero-latency are maxims you will valuate a lot in later weeks, if understood why. For the details on {default- *(not always safe )* | hi-perf- | secure- }-configuration details, the best is to read the native API ( best in ver 3.x, not the most recent one ). There you start realise many additional powers, not mentioned in the book or elsewhere. **But definitely go for the book**. Worth your time, sweat, blood and tears, if you are into a serious distributes-computing. G/L!

Comment: I was just checking `CONFLATE` only keeps the last message. However in my case I want to save the information of the past messages, to be processed all together with the last message. Else I would lose information. Vote up in any case for your interesting answer and also the reference to your other answer. I'll check out the book =)

Comment: Right on-spot, the `CONFLATE` option was named and labeled explicitly as *"a reversed feature to this"*, as it makes sense for some other use-case scenarios, as being an almost anti-pattern to your one. Reasons are obvious and such settings help save a lot in stability-bothered tight real-time control-loops, where "over-sampled" inputs do not create any better results, but can devastate computing-resources work-flows stability within a given R/T-control theory envelopes.

Answer (score 1):

If `isLastMessage()` is meant to identify the last message within the stream of messages produced by `publisher.py`, than this is impossible since there is no last message. `publisher.py` produces an infinite amount of messages!

However, if `publisher.py` knows its last "real" message, i.e. no `while True:`, it could send a "I am done" message afterwards. Identifying that in `subscriber.py` is trivial.