ZeroMQ Load Balancing Broker 3 example, but with multiprocessing instead of multithreading in Python
I'm following along in the ZeroMQ book, and trying the Python examples. I'm at lbbroker3.py, and trying to switch it from using multithreading to multiprocessing in Python 3. I was looking at another python ZeroMQ multiprocessing example online from a blog, and tried to incorporate the least amount of changes.
Whenever I run my code, it hangs at joining the first worker thread. The worker thread seems to be hung on "socket.recv_multipart()".
######################################################################HERE IS MY CODE:
import zmq
from zmq.eventloop.ioloop import IOLoop
from zmq.eventloop.zmqstream import ZMQStream
from multiprocessing import Queue, Process, Event
import time
from time import sleep

NUM_CLIENTS = 12
NUM_WORKERS = 4

def client_proc(client_url, ident):
    # Basic request-reply client using REQ socket
    context = zmq.Context.instance()
    socket = context.socket(zmq.REQ)
    socket.identity = (u"Client-%d" % (ident)).encode('ascii')
    
    socket.connect(client_url)

    # Send request, get reply:
    socket.send(b"HELLO")
    reply = socket.recv()

    print("%s: %s\n" % (socket.identity.decode('ascii'),
                        reply.decode('ascii')), end='')

def worker_proc(ident, worker_url):
    # Before doing work, set up IPC via ZeroMQ
    # Note: Worker uses local REQ socket to connect to ROUTER socket in broker
    context = zmq.Context.instance()
    socket = context.socket(zmq.REQ)
    socket.identity = (u"Worker-%d" % (ident)).encode('ascii')
    socket.connect(worker_url)
    # Tell the broker we are ready for work
    socket.send(b"READY")
    try:
        while True:
            address, empty, request = socket.recv_multipart() # This line is where
            # the program hangs upon attempting to join first worker process.
            print("%s: %s\n" % (socket.identity.decode('ascii'),
                                request.decode('ascii')), end='')
            socket.send_multipart([address, b'', b'OK'])
    except zmq.ContextTerminated:
        # context terminated so quit silently
        return


class LRUQueue(object):
    # LRUQueue class using ZMQStream/IOLoop for event dispatching

    def __init__(self, backend_socket, frontend_socket):
        self.available_workers = 0
        self.is_workers_ready = False
        self.workers = []
        self.client_nbr = NUM_CLIENTS

        self.backend = ZMQStream(backend_socket)
        self.frontend = ZMQStream(frontend_socket)
        self.backend.on_recv(self.handle_backend)

        self.loop = IOLoop.instance()

    def handle_backend(self, msg):
        # Queue worker address for LRU routing
        worker_addr, empty, client_addr = msg[:3]

        assert self.available_workers < NUM_WORKERS

        # add worker back to the list of workers
        self.available_workers += 1
        self.is_workers_ready = True
        self.workers.append(worker_addr)

        # 2nd frame is empty
        assert empty == b""

        # Third frame is READY or else a client reply address
        # If client reply, send rest back to frontend
        if client_addr != b"READY":
            empty, reply = msg[3:]

            # Following frame is empty
            assert empty == b""

            self.frontend.send_multipart([client_addr, b'', reply])

            self.client_nbr -= 1
            print(f"num clients: {self.client_nbr}")

            if self.client_nbr == 0:
                # Exit after N messages
                self.loop.add_timeout(time.time() + 1, self.loop.stop)


        if self.is_workers_ready:
            # When at least 1 worker ready, start accepting frontend msgs
            self.frontend.on_recv(self.handle_frontend)

    def handle_frontend(self, msg):
        # Now get next client request, route to LRU worker
        # Client request is [address][empty][request]
        client_addr, empty, request = msg

        assert empty == b""

        # Dequeue and drop the next worker address
        self.available_workers -= 1
        worker_id = self.workers.pop()

        self.backend.send_multipart([worker_id, b'', client_addr, b'', request])
        if self.available_workers == 0:
            # stop receiving until workers become available again
            self.is_workers_ready = False
            self.frontend.stop_on_recv()


def main():

    #print("Number of CPU cores: ", multiprocessing.cpu_count())
    #num_workers = multiprocessing.cpu_count() - 1
    #num_workers = 2
    url_worker = "ipc://backend.ipc"
    url_client = "ipc://frontend.ipc"

    # Prepare our ZMQ context and sockets
    context = zmq.Context()
    frontend = context.socket(zmq.ROUTER)
    frontend.bind(url_client)
    backend = context.socket(zmq.ROUTER)
    backend.bind(url_worker)

    ## Generate grid of Mandelbrot values
    #gridvals = generate_mandelgrid(xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax, num_pixels, num_iters, max_val)

    # spawn worker processes
    workers = []
    clients = []
    for i in range(NUM_WORKERS):

        workers.append( Process(target=worker_proc, args=(i, url_worker)) )
        workers[i].start()

    for i in range(NUM_CLIENTS):
        clients.append( Process(target=client_proc, args=(url_client, i)) )
        clients[i].start()

    # Create queue with sockets
    queue = LRUQueue(backend, frontend)

    # Start reactor
    # NOTE: starting an IOLoop should be done AFTER all process forking. One IOLoop per process. no sharing.
    IOLoop.instance().start()


    print("Program Closing")
    sleep(1)
    frontend.close()
    backend.close()
    print("sockets closed")
    
    sleep(1)
    context.term()
    print("context terminated")

    i = 1
    for cli in clients:
        print(f"Joining Client {i}")
        cli.join()
        i += 1

    i = 1
    for work in workers:
        print(f"Joining Worker {i}")
        # Hangs at joining first worker
        work.join()
        i += 1

    print(f"NEVER REACHED HERE")

    return 0

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

###################################################################################
HERE IS THE OUTPUT WHEN I RUN IT:

$ python3 lbbroker3-mp.py
/home/rpc/workspace/src/multibrot/lbbroker3-mp.py:2:
VisibleDeprecationWarning: zmq.eventloop.minitornado is deprecated in
pyzmq 14.0 and will be removed.
Install tornado itself to use zmq with the tornado IOLoop.
from zmq.eventloop.ioloop import IOLoop Worker-0: HELLO Worker-2:
HELLO num clients: 11 Worker-3: HELLO Worker-1: HELLO num clients: 10
Client-0: OK Worker-0: HELLO num clients: 9 Client-1: OK Worker-2:
HELLO num clients: 8 Client-2: OK num clients: 7 Worker-3: HELLO
Client-3: OK Client-4: OK num clients: 6 num clients: 5 Worker-1:
HELLO Worker-0: HELLO Client-5: OK num clients: 4 Worker-3: HELLO
Worker-2: HELLO num clients: 3 num clients: 2 Client-6: OK Client-8:
OK Client-7: OK num clients: 1 Client-10: OK Client-9: OK Worker-3:
HELLO num clients: 0 Client-11: OK Program Closing sockets closed
context terminated Joining Client 1 Joining Client 2 Joining Client 3
Joining Client 4 Joining Client 5 Joining Client 6 Joining Client 7
Joining Client 8 Joining Client 9 Joining Client 10 Joining Client 11
Joining Client 12 Joining Worker 1
^CProcess Process-2: Process Process-4: Process Process-1: Traceback
(most recent call last):   File
"/home/rpc/workspace/src/multibrot/lbbroker3-mp.py", line 182, in

main()   File "/home/rpc/workspace/src/multibrot/lbbroker3-mp.py", line 174, in main
work.join()   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 149, in join
res = self._popen.wait(timeout)   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py", line 43, in wait
Traceback (most recent call last):
return self.poll(os.WNOHANG if timeout == 0.0 else 0)   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py", line 27, in poll
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 314, in
_bootstrap
self.run()   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)   File "/home/rpc/workspace/src/multibrot/lbbroker3-mp.py", line 37, in
worker_proc
address, empty, request = socket.recv_multipart() # This line is where   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/zmq/sugar/socket.py",
line 625, in recv_multipart
parts = [self.recv(flags, copy=copy, track=track)]   File "zmq/backend/cython/socket.pyx", line 781, in
zmq.backend.cython.socket.Socket.recv   File
"zmq/backend/cython/socket.pyx", line 817, in
zmq.backend.cython.socket.Socket.recv
pid, sts = os.waitpid(self.pid, flag)   File "zmq/backend/cython/socket.pyx", line 186, in
zmq.backend.cython.socket._recv_copy   File
"zmq/backend/cython/checkrc.pxd", line 13, in
zmq.backend.cython.checkrc._check_rc KeyboardInterrupt
KeyboardInterrupt Traceback (most recent call last): Traceback (most
recent call last):   File
"/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 314, in
_bootstrap
self.run()   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)   File "/home/rpc/workspace/src/multibrot/lbbroker3-mp.py", line 37, in
worker_proc
address, empty, request = socket.recv_multipart() # This line is where   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/zmq/sugar/socket.py",
line 625, in recv_multipart
parts = [self.recv(flags, copy=copy, track=track)]   File "zmq/backend/cython/socket.pyx", line 781, in
zmq.backend.cython.socket.Socket.recv   File
"zmq/backend/cython/socket.pyx", line 817, in
zmq.backend.cython.socket.Socket.recv   File
"zmq/backend/cython/socket.pyx", line 186, in
zmq.backend.cython.socket._recv_copy   File
"zmq/backend/cython/checkrc.pxd", line 13, in
zmq.backend.cython.checkrc._check_rc   File
"/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 314, in
_bootstrap
self.run()   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)   File "/home/rpc/workspace/src/multibrot/lbbroker3-mp.py", line 37, in
worker_proc
address, empty, request = socket.recv_multipart() # This line is where KeyboardInterrupt   File
"/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/zmq/sugar/socket.py", line 625, in
recv_multipart
parts = [self.recv(flags, copy=copy, track=track)]   File "zmq/backend/cython/socket.pyx", line 781, in
zmq.backend.cython.socket.Socket.recv   File
"zmq/backend/cython/socket.pyx", line 817, in
zmq.backend.cython.socket.Socket.recv   File
"zmq/backend/cython/socket.pyx", line 186, in
zmq.backend.cython.socket._recv_copy   File
"zmq/backend/cython/checkrc.pxd", line 13, in
zmq.backend.cython.checkrc._check_rc KeyboardInterrupt Process
Process-3: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 314, in
_bootstrap
self.run()   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)   File "/home/rpc/workspace/src/multibrot/lbbroker3-mp.py", line 37, in
worker_proc
address, empty, request = socket.recv_multipart() # This line is where   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/zmq/sugar/socket.py",
line 625, in recv_multipart
parts = [self.recv(flags, copy=copy, track=track)]   File "zmq/backend/cython/socket.pyx", line 781, in
zmq.backend.cython.socket.Socket.recv   File
"zmq/backend/cython/socket.pyx", line 817, in
zmq.backend.cython.socket.Socket.recv   File
"zmq/backend/cython/socket.pyx", line 186, in
zmq.backend.cython.socket._recv_copy   File
"zmq/backend/cython/checkrc.pxd", line 13, in
zmq.backend.cython.checkrc._check_rc KeyboardInterrupt


Please extract a [mcve] and provide that along with the output it creates. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask]. That said, some things already up front: In your worker's while loop, you repeatedly create a socket and connect. You should only do that once, ZMQ will do the rest, including re-connecting. socket.close() and context.term() are silly, because you neither do it on every object nor on every path through the code. Lastly, you never send "STOP", so it blocks forever waiting for a message.

Hello @UlrichEckhardt, I read what you suggested, and attempted to clean up my example code further. I've updated my post to include changed code and effective output. The same problem still exists, and the output should be the same. It hangs with all worker processes awaiting results from socket_receive_multipart, and i have to press ctrl + C to close it. Running the original lbbroker3.py works fine.

i feel dumb. it's in a while true... but the exception is never caught cause it's stuck waiting for input. But it seems there are a couple options. I'm still learning 0MQ. I'm reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7538988/zeromq-how-to-prevent-infinite-wait and maybe i should use a poller?
